# Encountering two errors when building unity for android, firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm receiving both errors:

Could not create task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'GoogleServicesTask'.

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each {
    ext {
        it.setProperty("android.useAndroidX", true)
        it.setProperty("android.enableJetifier", true)
    }
}
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://deltadna.bintray.com/android" // Assets/DeltaDNA/Editor/Android/Dependencies.xml:8
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.deltadna.android:deltadna-sdk-notifications:4.10.0' // Assets/DeltaDNA/Editor/Android/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[5,6)') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    }// Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing' 
    }// Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    } // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    } // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:6.16.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.16.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
    // ** revenuecat **
    implementation ('com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases-hybrid-common:1.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.billingclient', module: 'billing'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

I saw several threads that said i should remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
or to update `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` but that didn't do it for me and only caused more problems.

Also running `./gradlew :dependencies` didn't show anything.

Comment: Can you share a more detailed error log, which version of Unity, and which version of the Firebase SDK you're using? I have a few guesses but don't know which will help

guesses:
The Firebase Unity plugin does the google services work for you, removing `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` may fix it. Make sure you have google-services.json in your Assets/ directory and force resolve dependencies
In Unity 2020.1 and Firebase <= 6.15.2, the useAndroidX line won't work. Use this workaround: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-compatibility-with-unity-20201.html

Comment: I'm using unity 2019.1.13 and firebase 6.16.0.
I tried adding firebase several times using https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup but with no success. Today I found your tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6du3DUTIPI&t=627s&ab_channel=Firebase but still got the same results.
removing `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as you suggested gives me a lot of "duplicate class" errors between firebase analytics and google.gms
Furthermore I can say that I'm not using EDM4U because it didn't help several times and added other dependency that I didn't want there.

Comment: So, you'll want to run EDM4U at least once so it can do its work (the dependencies for Unity are not the same as the dependencies for Android in general). This will handle all the play services stuff for you (maybe reset the gradle file and have it fill up again). Make sure in your EDM4U settings, you have Jetifier and patch mainTemplate.gradle enabled (although it looks like you have Unity dependencies). My guess is that the duplicate class files are jetifier not running.

When  you do a Force Resolve, do you get any errors? Can you try generating a gradleTemplate.properties?

Comment: Another idea, keep the apply plugin out (again, the SDK will do this work), and try following this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-compatibility-with-unity-20201.html

In particular, try generating a gradleTemplate.properties file and add:

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: When I say "the SDK will do this work". The Google Services plugin, among other things, converts google-services.json into google-services.xml under the resources directory. The Firebase Unity plugin does this same thing automatically, as a workaround for Unity projects that aren't using Gradle.

Comment: I updated the version handler and then a pop up appeared asking me if I want to enable firebase analytics. The pop up in your tutorial at 8:28 doesn't show up and I don't have play service resolver under my assets tab. I tried using EDM4U again and removing `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` but getting the same errors. I don't see an option to generate gradleTemplate.properties under publishing, but when I updated the version handler and used EDM4U this line was added to my AndroidResolverDependencies.xml file  `<setting name="gradlePropertiesTemplateEnabled" value="False" />`.

Comment: The duplicate class erros are
`Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzt found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.6.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)`

  `Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.6.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2)`
 
and a lot more like these

Comment: Without seeing all of them, I'm guessing that it's AndroidX/Jetifier related. Namely, iirc, the Facebook plugin still uses the google support library and Firebase is on AndroidX. Jetifier will migrate support to AndroidX. I'll write up an answer _assuming_ this, but it still might not be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to exactly say what's happening, but I have a few suggestions that should work.

First, get rid of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` under `dependencies` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. The reason is that the purpose of this is to read a `google-services.json` file in your project directory and generate a `res/values/google-services.xml` file (more information [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)). The Firebase SDK for Unity will do this automatically placing this file under `Assets/Plugins/FirebaseApp.androidlib/res/values/google-services.xml`. Anything in a `Plugins/*.androidlib` file is now automatically pulled into the Android project, rendering this step redundant (and often causing errors both on the Unity and Android side).

Since you've used Unity to generate a `mainTemplate.gradle` file and you're using a newer version of Unity (2019.3 and above), you'll also need to generate a `gradleTemplate.properties` file. This way we can enable AndroidX (the replacement for the Android Support libraries now used by Firebase) and enable Jetifier (which will upgrade Google Support dependencies that it looks like Facebook is pulling in).

[image: Screenshot of the Project Settings window showing "Custom Main Gradle Template" and "Custom Base Gradle Template" checked]

From here, since you mentioned disabling the External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U), you will want to force resolve your Android dependencies.
[image: Screenshot showing "Force Resolve" under "Assets/External Dependency Manager/Android Resolver"]

You will want to have "Patch mainTemplate.gradle", "Use Jetifier.", and "Patch gradleTemplate.properties" all checked in your Android Resolver Settings for this to work:
[image: Screenshot of "Android Resolver Settings" showing the above options checked]

If you're running into issues or you don't want to run EDM4U, I'm trying to do is add `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` to `gradleTemplate.properties`. For my own game, this file now looks like:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx**JVM_HEAP_SIZE**M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableR8=**MINIFY_WITH_R_EIGHT**
**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

To recap, at this point you should have removed the play services plugin and enabled AndroidX and Jetifier support. You should be able to either build from Unity or export a gradle project and build from the command line (this latter is always a challenge in Unity since they opt to not use gradlew, so you may run into incompatibility with your system gradle).

If this doesn't help, I'd like to see a more complete error log to try to suss out the actual cause.

Comment: I can't see in my settings an option for Custom Gradle Properties Template, also in my AndroidResolverDependency.xml I have this line `<setting name="gradlePropertiesTemplateEnabled" value="False" />`. I tried to change it to `True` hoping it will make the option in the setting to appear but with no luck.
Everything else is done as you said.

Comment: Silly question: do you have any jar or aar files under `Assets/Plugins/Android`? Maybe `Assets/Plugins/Android/<library>/` (such as Firebase or Facebook for <library>)? If so, can you delete them?

Comment: I upgraded to unity 2019.4.9 LTS and now I can see and enable the Custom Base   Properties Template. I added it and the lines `android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true` were added automatically by the android resolver, yet i'm getting the same errors. The gradle file also changed after upgrading the unity version. To answer your question, yes I removed all the jar files under `Assets/Plugins/Android`, no files under any `<library>` and built the project, I'm still getting the `duplicate class` errors.

Comment: At this point I'm out of guesses. Definitely try asking at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues or https://firebase.google.com/support. They'll definitely want to see more of your build logs, and on GitHub it's super helpful if you can repro the issue on one of the quickstart projects.

Answer (score 0):

In your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (build.gradle), add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin. Check that you have Google's Maven repository, as well.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
}
```

And then:

In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with combo `Firebase`+`Unity`+`gradle`. Solved by downgrading `gradle`.

> `Unity` -> `Edit` -> `Preference` -> `Gradle` to version `6.7.1`

It seems that `Firebase` could not work with newer `gradle` versions.

Download: [Gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)